# Установить цвет фона для ActionBar

Tags: java, android

Хочу изменить цвет фона `ActionBar` на свой. 
Делаю так:

В `strings.xml` добавил нужный мне цвет - `actBar`

Создал файл `themes.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="backGTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@color/actBar</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@color/actBar</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

К нужной мне Activity установил эту тему

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/backGTheme">
```

Захожу в приложение - Цвет фона `ActionBar` не изменился + ко всему еще пропало название приложения.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Про добавление цвета в strings.xml поподробнее.

Answer (score 2):

ну если атрибут просит стиля, вы ему его и давайте:

```
 <resources>
    <style name="backGTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

ActionBar устарел, вместо него используй Toolbar. Чтобы изменить цвет стандартного ActionBar нужно достаточно повозиться создавая изображение в drawable, а для Toolbar достаточно указать в XML [Ссылка на туториал](http://androiddocs.ru/toolbar-alternativa-actionbar/)